# Sort trough command line output for connected devices

Tags: php, ubuntu, shell-exec

im working with PHP on my Raspberry PI, and im trying to find a file on a USB drive, this will be in a cron job for every minute...

The file has a name that i will know every time (settings.txt) and i have the required output to figure out what drives i have.. 
Now i cant figure out how to sort them...

Im writing them all to a text file but they are not spaced with \n on every line and not with \t between them... how is it possible to get the value of "Mounted On" ?

Output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        3648564 3479396    152784  96% /
devtmpfs          469756       0    469756   0% /dev
tmpfs             474060     452    473608   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             474060    6928    467132   2% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             474060       0    474060   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     65480   20256     45224  31% /boot
tmpfs              94812      48     94764   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       15625744 5330752  10294992  35% /media/kristian/D81C-745F
```

Device info:
OS: Ubuntu Mate 15.**
PHP: 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk for this. It splits by space by default. For my Mac it was $9 and for one of my Centos boxes it's $6. Just depends on which column your value is. Looks like it's a $6.

```
df  | awk '{print $6}'                                                                       

Mounted
/
/tmp
/usr/local
/var
/dev
/Volumes/MobileBackups
/Volumes/AppCode
/Volumes/LaCie
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured i could use this code after searching for hours:

```
<?php
$df = array();
echo "reading `df` command \n";
exec("df -T -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs -P -B 1G",$df);
array_shift($df);
$Stats = array();
foreach($df as $disks){
    $split = preg_split('/\s+/', $disks);
    $Stats[] = array(
        'disk'      => $split[0],
        'mount'     => $split[6],
        'type'      => $split[1],
        'mb_total'  => $split[2],
        'mb_used'   => $split[3],
        'mb_free'   => $split[4],
        'percent'   => $split[5],
    );
}
echo "Completed device scan... \n";
```